# How do I do this double join on the same table

Tags: mysql

How do I do a double join on the same table?

Basically, I want to do this:

`1 - Sort all records in descending order by a order_date_last_revised column.
2 - Group those records by order_base_id column to eliminate duplicates.
3 - Match the id of those records and return all columns for them.`

Here is my SQL, it doesn't work:

`SELECT
    *
FROM sys_quote_master q1 
LEFT JOIN sys_quote_master q2 ON q1.order_id = q2.order_id group by q2.order_base_id 
LEFT JOIN sys_quote_master q3 ON q2.order_id = q3.order_id WHERE order_base_id="010313-6063" order by q3.order_date_last_revised desc;`

Basically, I get this when I try to execute it:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'LEFT JOIN sys_quote_master q2 ON q1.order_id = q2.order_id order by q3.order_dat' at line 4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `group by` is out if place: It must appear after the tables and after the where clause (if any):

```
SELECT *
FROM sys_quote_master q1 
LEFT JOIN sys_quote_master q2 ON q1.order_id = q2.order_id 
LEFT JOIN sys_quote_master q3 ON q2.order_id = q3.order_id
WHERE order_base_id="010313-6063"
group by q2.order_base_id 
order by q3.order_date_last_revised desc;
```

Note however that the group by as it stands will not be useful; you must list all columns that are not aggregate columns to function as expected.

Perhaps group by is not what you want - consider using `distinct` to imitate duplicates:

```
select distinct *
from ...
-- and remove group by clause
```

Comment: Hi - wow...you are incredible...thank you so much for such a quick response...I run your query and it now works, but I am not getting the right results.

Basically, I have these 3 records with order_id's 21868, 21869, and 21871.  They all have the same order_base_id value of '010313-6063'.  But they have 3 different date time stamps for order_date_last_revised column.

How can I sort them by date in descending order, then eliminate the duplicate ones based on duplicate order_base_id column only, and then return all their columns, basically, I think only 21871 should be returned instead.

Comment: But I am getting 21868.  Also, using distinct *, returns all 3 because  they all have different order_id and different dates.  I just want them distinct by eliminating only the ones with the duplicate column value of '010313-6063' in order_base_id column, so I just want them to be distinct by this column only.

Comment: I think I need to figure out a way to do order by first, then group by, and then select all columns...:)

Comment: What about this?

`SELECT * FROM
sys_quote_master AS g1
JOIN (SELECT order_id, order_base_id, max(order_date_last_revised) as mostrecent 
      FROM sys_quote_master WHERE order_base_id="010313-6063" group by order_base_id) AS g2
ON g2.mostrecent = g1.order_date_last_revised
ORDER BY g1.order_id;`

Comment: Almost. Change the group by of the inner query to `group by order_id, order_base_id`

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

`SELECT * FROM
sys_quote_master AS g1
JOIN (SELECT order_id, order_base_id, max(order_date_last_revised) as mostrecent 
      FROM sys_quote_master WHERE order_base_id="010313-6063" group by order_base_id) AS g2
ON g2.mostrecent = g1.order_date_last_revised
ORDER BY g1.order_id;`